# how to display radio button label in front of the radio button?

Tags: asp.net, css

I was trying to use radio button control in asp.net but I'm experiencing a problem that, the label of the radio button is getting displayed under the radio button. I want to use it in front of the radio button. Is there any property of a radio button with which the label can be displayed in front of the radio button.?

Comment: Could you post your HTML/CSS? They should both be inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the text that you add is long or space for total control is less so the text is getting wrapped. Try giving some large fixed width to the control. It would be better if you post some code.

Comment: no. it's not because of that.. i have tried giving larger size. but still not working.